# Status of large-scale structure formation within cosmology today

Tags: astrophysics, specific-reference, research-level, cosmology

Since the CMB results of the past decade, would it be fair to say that the consensus among cosmologists is that cosmic strings are no longer considered as a (major) source for density perturbations?

If so, what are the leading theories to explain how the universe developed inhomogeneity from a nearly uniform early universe?

What are the active areas of research for within structure formation today, besides relying upon relativistic perturbation methods? Is there a recent review for a status of the field today?

Comment: Now that the Planck data is out, much stricter constraints have been placed on cosmic strings.  See http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.5085 by the Planck Collaboration.